# Using Maven build profiles to change code/change injected beans

Tags: java, maven, build

Our code base has an external properties service on which it depends.  For development it requires devs to separately start and initialize the external service locally before they can fire up the code.  This is annoying.

We could provide a dummy stub service that would let developers do thier thing without the extra steps.  We already use Maven build profiles.

Does Maven provide any elegant mechanism that we could use to inject the dummy stub service (based on a dev build profile) and that would have little impact (littering) on our nice production shipped code?

I was thinking of the resource plugin but this requires a properties file which we don't want.  The external service was originally designed to get rid of properties files

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you could use the Maven Compiler Plugin and include or eclude classes on different profiles, then implement some code that check if the classes are presents and call it by reflection, depend if is a SE o EE project, in EE you have other possible solutions.